# django annotate weird behavavior (group by model.id)

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-orm, django-aggregation, django-annotate

In my DRF API, I have a view like this

```
class ActivityAPI(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, TokenAuthentication)
    serializer_class = ActivitySerializer
    queryset = Activity.objects.order_by('-id').all()
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = ActivityFilter
    filter_fields = ('name', 'ack', 'developer', 'ack_date', 'ack_by', 'verb')    

    def get_count(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        if CASE_1:
            queryset = queryset.values('verb').annotate(count=Count('verb'))
        if CASE_2:
            queryset = Activity.objects.values('verb').annotate(count=Count('verb'))
        return Response(data=queryset)
```

In **CASE_2**, I got what i expected which is equivalent to SQL query

```
SELECT `activity_activity`.`verb`, COUNT(`activity_activity`.`verb`) AS `count` FROM `activity_activity` GROUP BY `activity_activity`.`verb` ORDER BY NULL
```

But when it's comes to **CASE_1**, the annotate feature groups  the queryset by `activity.id` , that is

```
SELECT `activity_activity`.`verb`, COUNT(`activity_activity`.`verb`) AS `count` FROM `activity_activity` GROUP BY `activity_activity`.`id` ORDER BY `activity_activity`.`id` DESC`
```

**NOTE** I need url based filtered data for both API and Aggregation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Groups are so small because you have `.order_by('-id')` on the original queryset. You can fix it by an empty order_by or by sorting only by fields used in group by:

```
if CASE_1:
    queryset = queryset.values('verb').annotate(count=Count('verb')).order_by('verb')
```

Read about [Aggregation - Interaction with default ordering or order_by()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by).